# Check for Specific Username Password Expire Script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

I never posted before, but I search here quite often and you all are usually extremely helpful.

I have had a issue with User Passwords expiring, and since I dont check /var/cron/log on the regular I never know these users are expiring, making certain nightly jobs not run.

With this script, I want to be able to check for these particular users password expiration and mail ourselves a reminder.

I saw plenty of examples online, but I have a thing of borrowing from or editing code I cant understand as I want to understand what I am writing, and what the code is doing, helps me learn better.

Below is some code I've written to a way I can understand and work with, but it doesnt seem to be working, as I still get a email for every Admin user saying username will expire even though I know that isnt true.

Any Suggestions? And sorry if this was lengthy

Code:

```
#Author:Emmanuel Iroanya Jr
#Edited: 
#Date:December 20th, 2012
#Purpose: The purpose of this is to check the Shadow table for the epoch value and warn the users / Email of Password Expiration  seven days in advance
ID=`id | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
if [[ "${ID}" != "uid=0(root)" ]]
then
   echo "You Need To Be Root To Run This Script, Please and Thank You"
   exit 1
fi
export Shadow=/etc/shadow
EpochSh=`perl -e 'print time, "\n"'`
export Hostname=`hostname`
#Our SSE Email Address that will get notification
export Email="emmanuel@mycompany.com"
for line in `cat $Shadow | grep adm`
do
 echo $line
done >passFile.txt
for i in `cat passFile.txt`
do
User=`echo $i |cut -d ':' -f 1`
MaxDay=`echo $i | cut -d ':' -f 5`
echo "$MaxDay"
Epoch=`echo $i |cut -d ':' -f 3`
Eval=`$MaxDay+$Epoch-$EpochSh`
echo "$Eval"
                 if [[ $Eval -lt 7 ]]
                 then
                 echo "Password for unix user $User on `hostname` is going to expire in less than a week. Please change it ASAP" | mailx -s 'Password Expiration ' $Email
                 elif [[ $Eval -le 0 ]]
                 then
                 echo "PASSWORD FOR USER $User HAS EXPIRED.PLEASE CHANGE IT ASAP TO AVOID PRODUCTION CRON JOBS FROM FAILING AND THE RESULTING LATE NIGHT CALLS" | mailx -s 'Password Expiration ' $Email
                 fi
done
```

Comment: One suggestion is to use the `chage -l` command to derive the password expiration information. It might simplify your script.

Comment: I do not think that my system has that command, as I just tried i and it did not work and there is no manual entry for that command when i do a man chage command

Comment: by the way, the /usr/bin/chage command is part of the shadow-utils RHEL package.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you get email for every admin is that there is a problem in the line:

```
Eval=`$MaxDay+$Epoch-$EpochSh`
```

That is trying to the 'Eval' variable to the result of a command formed by whatever the variables $MaxDay, $Epoch, and $EpochSh happen to be. In my case, that turned out to be `99999+13937-1358541158` which is not a command and therefore Eval got set to null which is always less than 7. Therefore the email about the password expiring in less than a week is always sent.

Here are more suggestions to improve the script. If this is a Linux system, then the parsing of the records from the shadow file are incorrect. "MaxDay", which is the number of days after which the password must be changed,  should be set from field number 4 instead of 5. Note that if MaxDay is 99999 or 0, then then password does not expire. "Epoch", which represents the date and time when the password was last changed, should be taken from field number 2 instead of 3. The equation for calculating the "Eval" variable should also be changed to something like:

```
eval Eval=`echo '( $MaxDay + $Epoch ) - ( $EpochSh / 86400 ) ' | bc`
```

That will return the number of days after which the password will expire.

Comment: Looking at what you put, I will make that change. but I agree the math doesnt look right at all. I calculating Eval like that from a suggestion someone gave me. but I think he may be mistaken.

What should my math look like then?

Comment: @gkelly1117 I have added the answer to your math question along with field number corrections which should take place in your `cut` commands.

Comment: I have those numbers in my cut because it is my understanding that /etc/shadow fields are  1.User name
2.Password: It your encrypted password
3.Last password change (lastchanged): Days since Jan 1, 1970 that password was last changed
4.Minimum: The minimum number of days required between password changes 
5.Maximum: The maximum number of days the password is valid (after that user is forced to change his/her password)
6.Warn : The number of days before password is to expire that user is warned that his/her password must be changed

Comment: also the error I get when I make your changes is as follows

    `syntax error on line 1, teletype`

Comment: @gkelly1117, what kind of system are you working on? The shadow file may be different than on the RHEL system I'm looking at. Before line 1 was a comment. What does line 1 look like now?

Comment: I am using a RHEL System as well, I found my error was with the bc built in calculator, I ended up spliting the expression to make it work. I posted a Answer to this with my new code and new issue. Maybe u can view it below

Answer (score 0):

@ZaSter thanks for the help, I ended up spliting the expression up, see full code below:

```
#!/bin/ksh -x
#Author:Emmanuel Iroanya Jr
#Date:December 20th, 2012
#Purpose: The purpose of this is to check the Shadow table for the epoch value and warn the users / Email of Password Expiration  seven days in advance
ID=`id | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
if [[ "${ID}" != "uid=0(root)" ]]
   then
   echo "You Need To Be Root To Run This Script, Please and Thank You"
   exit 1
fi
export Shadow=/etc/shadow
export EpochSh=`perl -e 'print time, "\n"'`
export Hostname=`hostname`
#Our SSE Email Address that will get notification
export Email="mygroup@mycompany.com"
for line in `cat $Shadow | grep adm`
do
 echo $line
done >passFile.txt
for i in `cat passFile.txt`
do
User=`echo $i |cut -d ':' -f 1`
MaxDay=`echo $i | cut -d ':' -f 5`
echo "$MaxDay"
Epoch=`echo $i |cut -d ':' -f 3`
echo "$Epoch"
Eval1=`expr $MaxDay + $Epoch`
Eval2=`expr $EpochSh / 86400`
Eval=`expr $Eval1 - $Eval2`
#export Eval=$(echo '( $MaxDay + $Epoch ) - ( $EpochSh / 86400 ) ' | bc)
echo "$Eval"
             if [[ $Eval -lt 7 ]]
             then
             echo "Password for unix user $User on `hostname` is going to expire in less than a week. Please change it ASAP" | mailx -s 'Password Expiration ' $Email
             elif [[ $Eval -le 0 ]]
             then
             echo "PASSWORD FOR USER $User HAS EXPIRED.PLEASE CHANGE IT ASAP TO AVOID PRODUCTION CRON JOBS FROM FAILING AND THE RESULTING LATE NIGHT CALLS" | mailx -s 'Password Expiration ' $Email
             fi
done
```

however, my last and final issue is how to deal with a username like below where a passwd -x -1 was used to set the password to never expire. So the MaxDay variable is blank and this is what is causing them all to alarm, it gets a blank value passes it in and the number obviously will be lower that 7 or 0 and causes the email

Example:

```
+ + cut -d : -f 1
+ echo testingadm:.ezNz7T6WZLK.:15730::::::
User=newadm
+ + cut -d : -f 5
+ echo testingadm:.ezNz7T6WZLK.:15730::::::
MaxDay=
+ echo
+ + cut -d : -f 3
+ echo testingadm:.ezNz7T6WZLK.:15730::::::
Epoch=15730
+ echo 15730
15730
+ + expr + 15730
expr: syntax error
Eval1=
+ + expr 1359133813 / 86400
Eval2=15730
+ + expr - 15730
expr: syntax error
Eval=
+ echo
+ [[  -lt 7 ]]
+ mailx -s Password Expiration  mygroup@mycompany.com
+ hostname
 + echo Password for unix user newadm on cmap01 is going to expire in less than a week. Please change it ASAP
```

Comment: Seems like this would solve the blank MaxDay problem:

    MaxDay=`echo $i | cut -d ':' -f 5`
    if [ "$MaxDay" == "" ]; then
        MaxDay=99999
    fi

Comment: the formatting of my comment lost the new lines. So I am trying again. Add a line or lines to check if [ "$MaxDay" == "" ]; then MaxDay=99999 fi

Comment: @ZaSter I ended up changing the variable for my first expression to Eval1=`expr ${MaxDay:-99999} + $Epoch` and the code worked like a charm.